# How can I get the sum of all the values from a dynamically generated column?

Tags: javascript, xml

So I have this code where I get the values from an XML file and dynamically create a table displaying the data. Where I am getting stuck at is when I am trying to get the totals from a specific column and then displaying them at the bottom. For example;

Column 3
3
5
6
Total 14

I can actually create and console.log a listNode but I can't necessarily do anything with that list. Thanks for your help.

This is the HTML code:

```
   `<div id='employees-student'>
    <table id='record' cellpadding='10px' style="text-align:left;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Week</th>
                <th>Date Range</th>
                <th>Appointments</th>
                <th>Tested Drive Through</th>
                <th>Positive Drive Through</th>
                <th>Positive Tested Offsite</th>
                <th>Cumulative Positive Rate</th>
                <th>Hospitalized Drive Through</th>
                <th>Hospitalized Tested Offsite</th>
            </tr>                
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div><!--content ends-->
`
```

This is the JavaScript code:

```
    <script>

window.onload = function () {

const recordsTableRows = function() {
let data = '';

let tableRecords = document.querySelector('#record');

let totals = document.querySelector('.totals');


fetch('DataDashboard.xml').then(function(resp) {
    return resp.text();
}).then(function(data) {


    let parser = new DOMParser(),
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/xml');
    let records = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('RECORD');
    let totals = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('RECORD');
    let cumulative = 0;
    let positives = 0;
    let tested = 0;
    let posDrive = 0;
    let posTested = 0;
    let testDrive = 0;


    records.forEach(recordXmlNode => {


    let row = document.createElement('tr');

    //Week
    let td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerText = recordXmlNode.children[9].innerHTML;
    row.appendChild(td);

    //Date Range
    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerText = recordXmlNode.children[0].innerHTML;
    row.appendChild(td);

    //Appointments
    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerText = recordXmlNode.children[1].innerHTML;
    row.appendChild(td);

    // const appointmentsArr = td.innerText;

    //Tested Drive Through  
    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerText = recordXmlNode.children[2].innerHTML;
    row.appendChild(td);

    testDrive += Number(recordXmlNode.children[2].innerHTML);


    //Positive Drive Through
    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerText = recordXmlNode.children[3].innerHTML;
    row.appendChild(td);

    posDrive += Number(recordXmlNode.children[3].innerHTML);


    //Positive Tested Offsite
    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerText = recordXmlNode.children[4].innerHTML;
    row.appendChild(td);

    posTested += Number(recordXmlNode.children[4].innerHTML);

    //Cumultive
    td = document.createElement('td');
    positives += Number(parseFloat(recordXmlNode.children[3].innerHTML) + parseFloat(recordXmlNode.children[4].innerHTML));
    tested += Number(parseFloat(recordXmlNode.children[2].innerHTML));
    cumulative = Math.floor((positives / tested) * 100) + "%";
    td.innerText = cumulative;
    row.appendChild(td);

    //Hospitalized Drive Through
    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerText = recordXmlNode.children[7].innerHTML;
    row.appendChild(td);

    //Hospitalized Tested Offsite
    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerText = recordXmlNode.children[8].innerHTML;
    row.appendChild(td);

    tableRecords.children[1].appendChild(row);

    //  console.log(posDrive);
    //  console.log(posTested);
    console.log(testDrive);

    });//records end
});//fetch end
};//recordsTableRows end


recordsTableRows();
</script>
```

This is an XML Example:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<RECORDS>
    <RECORD>
        <week>3/16-20</week>
        <appointments>6</appointments>
        <empStdsTested>2</empStdsTested>
        <empStdsPositive>0</empStdsPositive>
        <empStdsPosHospital>0</empStdsPosHospital>
        <patientsTested>4</patientsTested>
        <patientsPositive>0</patientsPositive>
        <empStdsPosOffsite>1</empStdsPosOffsite>
        <empStdsPosHospitalOffsite>0</empStdsPosHospitalOffsite>
        <weekNumber>1</weekNumber>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <week>3/23-27</week>
        <appointments>9</appointments>
        <empStdsTested>5</empStdsTested>
        <empStdsPositive>1</empStdsPositive>
        <empStdsPosHospital>0</empStdsPosHospital>
        <patientsTested>4</patientsTested>
        <patientsPositive>1</patientsPositive>
        <empStdsPosOffsite>1</empStdsPosOffsite>
        <empStdsPosHospitalOffsite>1</empStdsPosHospitalOffsite>
        <weekNumber>2</weekNumber>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <week>3/30-4/3</week>
        <appointments>4</appointments>
        <empStdsTested>3</empStdsTested>
        <empStdsPositive>1</empStdsPositive>
        <empStdsPosHospital>0</empStdsPosHospital>
        <patientsTested>1</patientsTested>
        <patientsPositive>1</patientsPositive>
        <empStdsPosOffsite>1</empStdsPosOffsite>
        <empStdsPosHospitalOffsite>0</empStdsPosHospitalOffsite>
        <weekNumber>3</weekNumber>
    </RECORD>
</RECORDS>
```

Comment: If this were mine, I'd make an object array from that xml so I could just use that to generate the table and add up any fields or sort or whatever on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using query selector already, but not to its full potential. You can use it to fetch the child elements by name, which makes your code a lot more readable and maintainable.

If you use `Àrray.from()` to convert the records into an array, you get access to the `reduce()` method. This allows you to reduce the list of XML elements into specific totals.

```js
const xmlString = getXMLString();
const dataDocument = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmlString, 'text/xml');
// fetch records from XML and store them in an array
const records =  Array.from(dataDocument.querySelectorAll('RECORD'));

// get the HTML elements and remove their contents
const tableFootRow = document.querySelector('#record tfoot tr');
tableFootRow.textContent = '';
const tableBody = document.querySelector('#record tbody');
tableBody.textContent = '';
    
// iterate the records
records.forEach(
  (record) => {
    // add a row
    const tr = tableBody.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
        
    // read data into variables
    const empStdsTested = +record.querySelector('empStdsTested')?.textContent || 0;
    const empStdsPositive = +record.querySelector('empStdsPositive')?.textContent || 0;
    const empStdsPosHospital = +record.querySelector('empStdsPosHospital')?.textContent || 0;
    const patientsTested = +record.querySelector('patientsTested')?.textContent || 0;
    const patientsPositive = +record.querySelector('patientsPositive')?.textContent || 0;
    const empStdsPosOffsite = +record.querySelector('empStdsPosOffsite')?.textContent || 0;
    const empStdsPosHospitalOffsite = +record.querySelector('empStdsPosHospitalOffsite')?.textContent || 0;
        
    tr
      // create and append table cell
      .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
      // fetch and assign column specific value
      .textContent = record.querySelector('weekNumber')?.textContent || '';
    tr
      .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
      .textContent = record.querySelector('week')?.textContent || '';
    tr
      .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
      .textContent = record.querySelector('appointments')?.textContent || '';
    tr
      .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
      .textContent = empStdsTested;
    tr
      .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
      .textContent = empStdsPositive;
    tr
      .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
      .textContent = empStdsPosHospital;
    tr
      .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
      .textContent = ((empStdsPositive + empStdsPosHospital) / empStdsTested * 100).toFixed(2) + '%';
    tr
      .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
      .textContent = empStdsPosOffsite;
    tr
      .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
      .textContent = empStdsPosHospitalOffsite;
  }
);

// add spacer cell for the first two columns
tableFootRow
  .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
  .setAttribute('colspan', 2);
    
// sum up appointments and add total
tableFootRow
  .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
  .textContent = records.reduce(
    (carry, current) => carry + (+record.querySelector('appointments')?.textContent || 0),
    0
  );
      
// read totals into variables
const totals = records.reduce(
  (carry, record) => ({
    empStdsTested: carry.empStdsTested + (+record.querySelector('empStdsTested')?.textContent || 0),
    empStdsPositive: carry.empStdsPositive+ (+record.querySelector('empStdsPositive')?.textContent || 0),
    empStdsPosHospital: carry.empStdsPosHospital+ (+record.querySelector('empStdsPosHospital')?.textContent || 0),
    patientsTested: carry.patientsTested+ (+record.querySelector('patientsTested')?.textContent || 0),
    patientsPositive: carry.patientsPositive+ (+record.querySelector('patientsPositive')?.textContent || 0),
    empStdsPosOffsite: carry.empStdsPosOffsite+ (+record.querySelector('empStdsPosOffsite')?.textContent || 0),
    empStdsPosHospitalOffsite: carry.empStdsPosHospitalOffsite+ (+record.querySelector('empStdsPosHospitalOffsite')?.textContent || 0)
  }),
  {
    empStdsTested: 0,
    empStdsPositive: 0,
    empStdsPosHospital: 0,
    patientsTested: 0,
    patientsPositive: 0,
    empStdsPosOffsite: 0,
    empStdsPosHospitalOffsite: 0,
  }
);
tableFootRow
  .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
  .textContent = totals.empStdsTested;
tableFootRow
  .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
  .textContent = totals.empStdsPositive;
tableFootRow
  .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
  .textContent = totals.empStdsPosHospital;
tableFootRow
  .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
  .textContent = ((totals.empStdsPositive + totals.empStdsPosHospital) / totals.empStdsTested * 100).toFixed(2) + '%';
tableFootRow
  .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
  .textContent = totals.empStdsPosOffsite;
tableFootRow
  .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
  .textContent = totals.empStdsPosHospitalOffsite;

function getXMLString() {
  return  `<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
    <RECORDS>
        <RECORD>
            <week>3/16-20</week>
            <appointments>6</appointments>
            <empStdsTested>2</empStdsTested>
            <empStdsPositive>0</empStdsPositive>
            <empStdsPosHospital>0</empStdsPosHospital>
            <patientsTested>4</patientsTested>
            <patientsPositive>0</patientsPositive>
            <empStdsPosOffsite>1</empStdsPosOffsite>
            <empStdsPosHospitalOffsite>0</empStdsPosHospitalOffsite>
            <weekNumber>1</weekNumber>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD>
            <week>3/23-27</week>
            <appointments>9</appointments>
            <empStdsTested>5</empStdsTested>
            <empStdsPositive>1</empStdsPositive>
            <empStdsPosHospital>0</empStdsPosHospital>
            <patientsTested>4</patientsTested>
            <patientsPositive>1</patientsPositive>
            <empStdsPosOffsite>1</empStdsPosOffsite>
            <empStdsPosHospitalOffsite>1</empStdsPosHospitalOffsite>
            <weekNumber>2</weekNumber>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD>
            <week>3/30-4/3</week>
            <appointments>4</appointments>
            <empStdsTested>3</empStdsTested>
            <empStdsPositive>1</empStdsPositive>
            <empStdsPosHospital>0</empStdsPosHospital>
            <patientsTested>1</patientsTested>
            <patientsPositive>1</patientsPositive>
            <empStdsPosOffsite>1</empStdsPosOffsite>
            <empStdsPosHospitalOffsite>0</empStdsPosHospitalOffsite>
            <weekNumber>3</weekNumber>
        </RECORD>
    </RECORDS>`;
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<table id="record">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Week</th>
      <th>Date Range</th>
      <th>Appointments</th>
      <th>Tested Drive Through</th>
      <th>Positive Drive Through</th>
      <th>Positive Tested Offsite</th>
      <th>Cumulative Positive Rate</th>
      <th>Hospitalized Drive Through</th>
      <th>Hospitalized Tested Offsite</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
     <tr>
         
     </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```